# Calling cucumber methods from a module

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash

I'm writing calabash tests using `Ruby 2.3.0` and I'm having trouble calling cucumber methods from a module.

```
module A
    module_function
    def visible
        wait_for_elements_exist("Some element query")
    end
end
```

And :

```
Class B
    include A
end
```

When I call `B.visible` or define this in `B` :

```
def visible
    A::visible
end
```

And call `B.visible`, I get `NoMethodError` indicating `wait_for_elements_exist` in module A.

I've tried to `require 'calabash-cucumber/cucumber'` in the module and `include Calabash::Cucumber` in the module. It didn't work.

I can access all cucumber methods from other classes in my project, and I have required the cucumber in my `env.rb` so the library is loaded. I'd like to know how to access library functions from a module, or how to properly include things into my modules.

EDIT

I tried `include Calabash::Cucumber::WaitHelpers`

And `include Calabash::Cucumber::Operations`

Did not work. I replaced include with extend, and now I can access the methods, but that won't solve my problem.

What I need is

`AndroidModule < Calabash::Android::Operations`

`IosModule < Calabash::Cucumber::Operations`

In these modules I define methods that are different between platforms.

Then there's `ScreenModule` for various screens, where I define methods specific for the screen, and based on the test I launch, I need `ScreenModule` to include one of the platform modules.

I need access to `::Operations` from `ScreenModule`, but it won't find any of those methods.

I can't figure out, why I can't use `wait_for_elements_exist`, even if I've included `::Operations` moudle

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you are not including the right module in your module.

```
include Calabash::Cucumber::WaitHelpers
```

The longer answer depends on what you are trying to do.  Since it seems you are new to ruby, I recommend this approach:

```
# features/steps/my_steps.rb
module MyApp
  module A
    def visible(mark)
       wait_for_element_exist("* marked:'mark'")
    end
  end
end

World(MyApp::A) # Add your module to the Cucumber World.

Then(/^I touch next$/) do
  visible("Next")
  touch("* marked:'Next'")
end
```

You can see an example of this in the [CalSmoke project](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/features/step_definitions/alerts_steps.rb).

This is how you load modules into Cucumber.

Based on your comment, I see that you want to use the Page Object Model (POM).

We have examples of how to do this in the [x-platform-example repo](https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example) and in the [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/xplat-best-practices/).

You need to understand that there is a difference between how ruby loads code and how to expose methods to Cucumber.

If you are new to ruby, I recommend this book [Metaprogramming in Ruby](https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby-2). If you are new to Cucumber, I recommend this resources.

- [The Cucumber Book](https://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book)
- [Skills matter: Matt from Cucumber talk](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/3940-why-your-step-definitions-should-be-one-liners-and-other-pro-tips) # behind a free password wall
- [Pivotal Tracker: Testing](http://confreaks.tv/videos/larubyconf2013-it-s-not-your-test-framework-it-s-you)

Comment: What i'm trying to create here, is a module for page object methods that I can use for Android and iOS page objects, so I can share step definitions between both platforms.

For example a step from me would be:

`Then(/^I see login screen$/)do
   ... create login page object...
    login_screen.visible
    login_screen.do_stuff`

And I want to create modules for methods like `visible` and `do_stuff` so I can include the modules in iOS and Android page classes.

I got this working by extending `Calabash::Cucumber::Operations` in module A to get access to operations.